# Cannot figure out how to format values for for loop print outs

Tags: go

I am trying to change the output of a subcommand for a CLI plugin but struggling to get it to work correctly.  Currently it shows an ugly printed list; I want to format it into a nice table that's easier to read.  Without the table, it works fine...just looks ugly.  Adding in the table breaks it by saying "....used as a value".

I have tried declaring the line as a string array with no luck.  I'm missing something and not sure what.

```golang
    for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                stats, _ := ccclient.AppStats(app.Metadata.GUID)
                table := ui.Table([]string{"Sample Time", "Instance ID", "CPU %", "Memory (MB)", "Disk (MB)", "Cell IP:port"})
                for key, value := range stats {
                    tickerObject := []string{time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339), key}
                    //ui.Say(fmt.Sprintf("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s", time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339), key, fmt.Sprintf("%f", value.Stats.Usage.CPU), fmt.Sprintf("%f", (value.Stats.Usage.Mem/1024/1024)), fmt.Sprintf("%f", (value.Stats.Usage.Disk/1024/1024)), value.Stats.Host+":"+strconv.Itoa(value.Stats.Port)))}
                    table.Add(tickerObject)
                    table.Print()
                }
            case <-quit:
                ticker.Stop()
            }
        }
```

I expect a formatted output that looks cleaner, instead I get -

```golang
cannot use tickerObject (type []string) as type string in argument to table.Add
```

---

Current output (using the commented out ui.Say line), does not line up:

> Collecting stats on app fabric-tasks in space Functions Dev Testing
>   Ctrl-C to stop collection of stats
>
> Sample Time,instance #,cpu %,memory (MB),disk (MB),cell ip:port
>   2019-06-14T23:33:42-05:00, 0, 0.004659, 38.492188, 205.914062,
>   169.61.179.187:61440 2019-06-14T23:33:47-05:00, 0, 0.004659, 38.492188, 205.914062, 169.61.179.187:61440 2019-06-14T23:33:52-05:00, 0, 0.004659, 38.492188, 205.914062, 169.61.179.187:61440
>   2019-06-14T23:33:57-05:00, 0, 0.006533, 38.492188, 205.914062,
>   169.61.179.187:61440

I don't *think* the table is the issue, I think I'm just missing something ridiculously simple with how the data is being stored.  I think the table can only pull display a string (or at least all the examples of I have found in our internal documentation only call strings).

Comment: The problem is that you are adding a slice and not a string into your table. Why are you not using fmt.Sprintf() instead of the tickerObject at table.Add()?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/text/tabwriter/

Comment: @apxp Seems to break even harder when I change it to that -

"panic: strings: negative Repeat count"

Comment: @Peter thank you!  That did the trick....I added in tabwriter and it looks **so much better**.